# Unable to SSH into server with Ansible

Tags: ssh, ansible

Unable to SSH into server with Ansible.

```
$ ansible myserver -m ping -u username\@company.com -vvvvv
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
Loaded callback minimal of type stdout, v2.0
<ip.ad.dr.es> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: username@company.com
<ip.ad.dr.es> SSH: ansible.cfg set ssh_args: (-o)(ControlMaster=auto)(-o)(ControlPersist=60s)
<ip.ad.dr.es> SSH: ANSIBLE_REMOTE_PORT/remote_port/ansible_port set: (-o)(Port=22)
<ip.ad.dr.es> SSH: ANSIBLE_PRIVATE_KEY_FILE/private_key_file/ansible_ssh_private_key_file set: (-o)(IdentityFile="/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa")
<ip.ad.dr.es> SSH: ansible_password/ansible_ssh_pass not set: (-o)(KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no)(-o)(PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey)(-o)(PasswordAuthentication=no)
<ip.ad.dr.es> SSH: ANSIBLE_REMOTE_USER/remote_user/ansible_user/user/-u set: (-o)(User=username@company.com)
<ip.ad.dr.es> SSH: ANSIBLE_TIMEOUT/timeout set: (-o)(ConnectTimeout=10)
<ip.ad.dr.es> SSH: PlayContext set ssh_common_args: ()
<ip.ad.dr.es> SSH: PlayContext set ssh_extra_args: (-A)
<ip.ad.dr.es> SSH: found only ControlPersist; added ControlPath: (-o)(ControlPath=/Users/username/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r)
<ip.ad.dr.es> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o Port=22 -o 'IdentityFile="/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=username@company.com -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/Users/username/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r ip.ad.dr.es '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1469804843.87-104204648028091 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1469804843.87-104204648028091="` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1469804843.87-104204648028091 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"''
ip.ad.dr.es | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh.", 
    "unreachable": true
}
```

Able to log in to the same server by manually doing a SSH from my Mac.

```
ssh -p 22 -A -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa username\@company.com@ip.ad.dr.es -X -C
```

Any idea on how to troubleshoot this further?

Looked for /var/log/auth.log on this server, and did not find the file. Not sure which other file to look at to see what is going on.

Edit #1:
Also did this -

```
ssh_args: (-o)(ControlMaster=auto)(-o)(ControlPersist=60s)(-o)(ForwardAgent=yes)
```

i.e. added the ForwardAgent=yes to the ssh_args, and removed the --ssh-extra-args="-A". That did not help either.

Comment: Try `ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 ansible myserver -m ping -u username\@company.com -vvvv` – it can give some clues

Comment: you're running Ansible from your mac also?

Comment: @tedder42 - yes, I am on a Mac running El Capitan v10.11.6, and ansible version is 2.1.1.0.

Comment: I bet that username with an at symbol is confusing it. Not sure the solution.

Comment: @Konstantin - Running with ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 helped. Debug log showed "ControlPath too long." This - http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#control-path - helped fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

See comment on ControlPath being too long. This page - http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#control-path - has the fix.